# Drush can't write to /tmp

Tags: files, drush, 9

Drush does not seem to be able to move files to the tmp folder on my local machine. Changing the tmp folder location to for instance "sites/default/files" works, but I would like to know why it doesn't work with /tmp.

I am using this script from the fontawesome module:

```
$this->fileSystem->move($path . '/fontawesome-free-' . $fontawesome_library['version'] . '-web', $this->fileSystem->getTempDirectory() . '/temp_fontawesome', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

and I get the error

```
The specified file '/home/username/websites/frilaering_newest/web/libraries/fontawesome/fontawesome-free-6.1.0-web' could not be moved to '/tmp/temp_fontawesome'.
```

The weird thing is that everything else seems to work - including file uploads, which uses the tmp folder - so can this be related to Drush somehow? I'm using Drush installed on the local website with composer. Everything looks fine in Drush status.

- www-data can write to /tmp
- /tmp is chmodded to 777
- .htaccess file is
  present in /tmp folder
- settings.local.php has "$settings["file_temp_path"] = '/tmp';"

I have tried anything - even fiddling with PrivateTmp, but the only thing that works is changing the tmp folder, which I would rather avoid.

I am using Drupal 9 with php7.3-fpm/apache2/mariaDB on latest Ubuntu

Any ideas?

Comment: You say that `www-data` can write to /tmp. This does matter for the web server, but not for Drush. The question is whether the user who has logged into the command line can write to /tmp.

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions on `/tmp/temp_fontawesome`? Which user is executing Drush?

Comment: Yes, also the sub directories.

Comment: the user who is using drush is my local user. I have permissions to write to /tmp as far as I can see.

the folder "temp_fontawesome" is never created because drush can't write to /tmp

Comment: could be typo related. Have you tried `../tmp` instead of `/tmp`? As an example I refer to my tmp folder like this `$settings['file_temp_path'] = '../tmp';`

Comment: thanks, but not a typo sadly. Also this seems to only affect drush. The site handles images and files without problems, and those go through /tmp too. This only happens when using drush.

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

Probably the `/tmp/temp_fontawesome` directory has already been created by the web server user `www-data`.

The permissions for `/tmp/temp_fontawesome` are probably:

```
ls -lash /tmp/temp_fontawesome
4,0K drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4,0K sep 21 13:55
```

...which means that your user, which is running drush, is not permitted to write to `/tmp/temp_fontawesome` because `other` has no write permision `r-x`, indicated by `-` instead of `w`.

### Solution A

Change the Linux group permissions, so that your user (called for example `drupaladmin`) running drush, is allowed to write to the directory:

```
sudo chgrp -R drupaladmin /tmp/temp_fontawesome
sudo chmod g+w -R /tmp/temp_fontawesome

ls -lash /tmp/temp_fontawesome
4,0K drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data drupaladmin  4,0K sep 21 13:56
```

### Solution A (could sometimes be the other way around)

If the directory is created by drush through your user first, then www-data cannot write to it. In that case the commands would be:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /tmp/temp_fontawesome
sudo chmod g+w -R /tmp/temp_fontawesome
```

### Solution B

Remove the directory (drush can then create the directory with your user as the owner):

```
sudo rm -r /tmp/temp_fontawesome
```